# How to remove cache storage for every newly generated Angular production builds?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, build

I have project running, for which I have to generate and deploy the production build everyday.
but whenever I add or upgrade to a new build, my index.html is not updated, it still tries to fetch older build files e.g. `runtime.xyz123.js` or `polyfills-es5.abcd1234.js"` , since these files don't exist anymore in build, the page goes blank, as browser is unable to find these files inside latest build.

**Workaround** -

1. **If I manually delete cache from history, or run the project on Incognito, it works fine**.
2. If I only enters my local server e.g. `http://192.168.0.164/` It works properly, *but with my base href(declared while creating builds) e.g. `http://192.168.0.164/angular/` it tries to fetch old build files and the webpage goes blank.*

[image]

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Web</title>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="/angular/">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.230892a2ce1e2d0e9693.css"></head>
<body>
  <script src="assets/js/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/moment-timezone.js"></script>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.71f44460add81ff0fb1e.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.950ea5f001d77cff122d.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills.05dd00906ab9ae4ef80e.js" defer></script><script src="main.5f0ba541bbf69328189e.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Angular version -

[image]

I use below build command to generated build -

> ng build --prod --output-hashing all --base-href /angular/

Please let me know, If there is something I can do to resolve this cache issue.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help you if your server support .htaccess files, I use this [htaccess generator](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator)

[You have to enable this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hJFK.png)
Do you want to prevent browser caching?

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. I get that the above link gives me some blocks of code, But where should I put that file in my Angular build environment, could you please let me know.

Comment: hello, first you need an apache server, and where you put your final bundle of angular you must put the file `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two solutions

1-The first solution add this script in your project:

add /build/post-build.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

// get application version from package.json
const appVersion = require('../package.json').version;

// promisify core API's
const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

console.log('\nRunning post-build tasks');

// our version.json will be in the dist folder
const versionFilePath = path.join(__dirname + '/../dist/version.json');

let mainHash = '';
let mainBundleFile = '';

// RegExp to find main.bundle.js, even if it doesn't include a hash in it's name (dev build)
let mainBundleRegexp = /^main.?([a-z0-9]*)?(\.bundle)?.js$/;

// read the dist folder files and find the one we're looking for
readDir(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'))
  .then(files => {
    mainBundleFile = files.find(f => mainBundleRegexp.test(f));

    if (mainBundleFile) {
      let matchHash = mainBundleFile.match(mainBundleRegexp);

      // if it has a hash in it's name, mark it down
      if (matchHash.length > 1 && !!matchHash[1]) {
        mainHash = matchHash[1];
      }
    }

    console.log(`Writing version and hash to ${versionFilePath}`);

    // write current version and hash into the version.json file
    const src = `{"version": "${appVersion}", "hash": "${mainHash}"}`;
    return writeFile(versionFilePath, src);
  }).then(() => {
    // main bundle file not found, dev build?
    if (!mainBundleFile) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Replacing hash in the ${mainBundleFile}`);

    // replace hash placeholder in our main.js file so the code knows it's current hash
    const mainFilepath = path.join(__dirname, '../dist/', mainBundleFile);
    return readFile(mainFilepath, 'utf8')
      .then(mainFileData => {
        const replacedFile = mainFileData.replace('{{POST_BUILD_ENTERS_HASH_HERE}}', mainHash);
        return writeFile(mainFilepath, replacedFile);
      });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error with post build:', err);
  });
```

update file package.json

```
"post-build": "node ./build/post-build.js"

And update build command(production) : npm build && npm run build --prod && npm run post-build
```

Create version-check.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class VersionCheckService {
    // this will be replaced by actual hash post-build.js
    private currentHash = '{{POST_BUILD_ENTERS_HASH_HERE}}';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    /**
     * Checks in every set frequency the version of frontend application
     * @param url
     * @param {number} frequency - in milliseconds, defaults to 30 minutes
     */
    public initVersionCheck(url, frequency = 1000 * 60 * 30) {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.checkVersion(url);
        }, frequency);
    }

    /**
     * Will do the call and check if the hash has changed or not
     * @param url
     */
    private checkVersion(url) {
        // timestamp these requests to invalidate caches
        this.http.get(url + '?t=' + new Date().getTime())
            .first()
            .subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    const hash = response.hash;
                    const hashChanged = this.hasHashChanged(this.currentHash, hash);

                    // If new version, do something
                    if (hashChanged) {
                        // ENTER YOUR CODE TO DO SOMETHING UPON VERSION CHANGE
                        // for an example: location.reload();
                    }
                    // store the new hash so we wouldn't trigger versionChange again
                    // only necessary in case you did not force refresh
                    this.currentHash = hash;
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.error(err, 'Could not get version');
                }
            );
    }

    /**
     * Checks if hash has changed.
     * This file has the JS hash, if it is a different one than in the version.json
     * we are dealing with version change
     * @param currentHash
     * @param newHash
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    private hasHashChanged(currentHash, newHash) {
        if (!currentHash || currentHash === '{{POST_BUILD_ENTERS_HASH_HERE}}') {
            return false;
        }

        return currentHash !== newHash;
    }
}
```

call this method in ngOnInit  of app.components.ts

```
this.versionCheckService.initVersionCheck(environment.versionCheckURL);
```

For more information check this link: https://blog.nodeswat.com/automagic-reload-for-clients-after-deploy-with-angular-4-8440c9fdd96c

2- The second use ServiceWorker

you can use this solution :

```
constructor(updates: SwUpdate) {
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      if (promptUser(event)) {
        updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
      }
    });
  }
```

For more information check the links:
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30705429)

Comment: @lissettdm  It's done thanks for your advice

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the response, My main issue is that my index.html itself is being cached, and showing old main.js files . hence whatever the latest code changes I add inside my angular project, it will still show the old copy of these files.